# Intel Core i7-8700k TDP at max turbo frequency?

Tags: cpu

Intel's site says that the TDP is 95W when running at base frequency (3.7GHz). However since the CPU uses Intel Turbo Boost Technology and has a max turbo frequency of 4.7GHz, I'm certain that the actual TDP is higher. Does anyone know how much it is?

Comment: [Intel Core i7-8700k review(overclocking)](http://www.guru3d.com/articles_pages/intel_core_i7_8700k_processor_review,27.html) from Guru3D. Take your conclusions

Comment: That article is not very helpful. They don't mention the CPU cooler properly (just vaguely points at a Corsair liquid cooler). I could have used that information to find the cooler's max TDP and then compare it...

Comment: Alright. I'm sure some youtuber like [Hardware Unboxed](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCI8iQa1hv7oV_Z8D35vVuSg) made a detailed review about the processor, worth checking out. Can't really help much since I don't own a 8700k (unfortunately)